# Calling a get method that returns just an int from another class?

Tags: java

For some reason I can't figure out the syntax and there are no basic and easy answers for my problem.

Lets say I have my main class:

```
package alpha;

public class Alpha{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(getNum());
    }
}
```

And I have my second class:

```
package alpha;

public class Beta{
    private int x = 5;

    public int getNum(){
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

How would I properly call getNum in my Alpha class? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a basic tutorial service. There are plenty of those out there already to learn the basics of your chosen language.

Comment: SO is for people at all levels. The OP clearly demonstrated what they had accomplished so far and explained what they were having trouble with. This is not a "gimme teh codez" question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to instantiate an instance of `Beta`. For example,

```
public class Alpha{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Beta myBeta = new Beta();
        System.out.println(myBeta.getNum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create beta in your scope.

```
Beta BETA = new Beta(); 
//then
BETA.getNum();
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive, so this will not compile.

Comment: Just a typo, I didn't write it in an IDE.

Comment: The class is `Beta`, not `beta`.

Answer (score 0):

To add another option: you could make the method static :

```
public class Beta{

   private static int x = 5;

   public static int getNum(){
    return x;
  }
}
```

And call it using :

```
Beta.getNum();
```